# Missed including undergraduate degree information in graduate application

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, united-kingdom

Whilst applying for a part-time graduate degree, I only stated my most recent graduate degree in the application (completed a year ago). I thought (possibly incorrectly) that I need only state the most recent and relevant information.

I did not state my earlier graduate degree (obtained 12 years ago) and undergraduate degree, received over 15 years ago.

I subsequently interviewed with the programme director regarding my application and I'm awaiting a decision on the outcome. During the interview call, there were no questions raised about the education information in my application?

How can I mitigate this situation? Should I call the department and supply the omitted information?

Comment: Did you also submit a full CV?

Answer (score 2):

If you know you’ve omitted information, I would correct the situation as soon as possible. If the information is received before a decision is made, then you cannot be accused later of hiding it. It may impact acceptance—materials weren’t sent according to deadline, after all—but you’re reducing your later exposure by coming forth now.